# Is there an R method that can keep numbers and discard text that are in the same value (e.g. 6 and a bit)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a task with a sample dataframe that includes messy data.

One of the issues are values that contain both number and text, e.g.

```
Heights
10
8
12
6 but a bit bent at the top
```

because of this the column is a Factor.
I have tried using as.numeric(as.character(f)) converts the number+text values into NA.

How can I keep the number (6) while removing the text (but a bit bent at the top)?

Comment: Try `as.numeric(grep("\\d+", f))`

Comment: well there are multiple ways to do it. if the offending number is in the beginning of the string you could use string::string_sub(data, from=1L, to=1L) or you can use any of the regex (regular expression) methods -> https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

Comment: How does your data appear?, can the sentence be like `but a bit bent 6 at the top 4`?? In this case do you want 6, 4 or both? or 64? You should definitely understand the underlying nature of your problem before you ask a SO question

Comment: @Onyambu It's a class exercise, so the data is messed up in every way imaginable.

Comment: And that still does not solve the problem. You have not responded as to whether you want 6 or 4 or 6 and 4 or 64 or 10 which is (6+4) etc when you have a vector like `but a bit bent 6 at the top 4`

Comment: @Onyambu, sorry. Yes, I want to keep all of the digits and decimals '.'
text and numbers are combined in different ways.
I think that I have got it working with regmatches(x$y, gregexpr("\\d+\\.\\d+", x$y))

Comment: Why not correct your answer with this regex instead of deleting your answer? This could be useful to others in the future.

Comment: @RuiBarradas  I was planning on submitting a new answer once I'd got it right.
I found that the regex I shared above is removing whole numbers, so it isn't correct yet

Comment: Put an asterisk after the period since the decimal point is optional. Tested with `x <- c("6 but a bit bent at the top", "6 text 1.2 other text 4")` the following works: `regmatches(x, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*", x))`.

Answer (score 0):

oh no. It's regex :(

x$y= regmatches(x$y, gregexpr("\d+|\d+\.\d+", x$y)) %>%

where:
x = dataframe
y = column name